# Interacting/Touching SKNode inside SCNPlane in ARKit does not work

Tags: swift, arkit, sknode, scnnode

I am trying to create a button on an ARKit project, so I created a plane on my sceneView on an ARKit project, to which I assigned a SKScene containing a button as material.

The button is a custom SKNode that detects touches to change color and call an action, however, even though I can detect touches on the SCNNode, I cannot detect them in the SKNode button.

The Node is placed this way:

```
func getButtonNode(_ title: String, origin: SCNVector3, moveTo: SCNVector3? = nil) {

    guard let _ = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame else {
        print("No current frame")
        return
    }

    let nodeHeight = imageReference!.physicalSize.height

    let sk = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 100))
    sk.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let button = ButtonNode(text: "  " + title + "  ")
    button.name = "button"
    button.setBackgroundColor(.white)
    button.setClickedTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped))

    sk.addChild(button)

    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: nodeHeight, height: nodeHeight/4)
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = sk
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

    let planeNode = SCNNode()
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = .pi / 2
    planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry
    planeNode.position = origin

    if let finalPosition = moveTo {
        planeNode.runAction(.move(to: finalPosition, duration: 0.5))
    }

    planeNode.name = "ButtonNode"

    self.node!.addChildNode(planeNode)

}
```

and part of the button code, which I got from apple is:

```
init(text txt: String) {
    super.init()

    // create a label
    lbl = SKLabelNode(text: txt)
    lbl!.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    lbl!.fontSize = 50
    lbl!.numberOfLines = 1
    lbl!.fontColor = UIColor.darkGray
    lbl!.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(200.0), y: CGFloat(50.0))
    lbl!.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 290
    lbl!.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    lbl!.verticalAlignmentMode = .center

    // create the background
    size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(lbl!.frame.size.width + 30.0), height: CGFloat(90.0))

    background = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 100), cornerRadius: 50)
    background!.fillColor = .white
    background!.lineWidth = 0

    // add to the root node
    addChild(background!)
    addChild(lbl!)

    // Track mouse event
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    setBackgroundColor(UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5))
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    setBackgroundColor(UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1))
    _ = (targetClicked! as AnyObject).perform(actionClicked, with: self)
}
```

I suspect setting a SKNode as material somehow eliminates is gesture recognition, but when I assign UI Elements like a UIWebView, I don't seem to have a problem with gestures.

Any ideas of how I could detect touches on my button?

Thanks in advance.